# send json from linux to firebase real-time db

Tags: linux, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to figure out a way to push a json file to my firebase real-time db that I want to use for dashboard data in my app. My idea is I already have the json file updated on the server every 5 seconds, then instead of the app and all the users pulling from the API, I would push it to the Database and the app would automatically display the updates. First time app development project and little knowledge.

researched all the documents I could find on Firebase. I can easily import the json manually but that doesn't help. I am hoping I could send from a bash script that I created as a service that processes the xml to json.